# cordova package iOS app shows white screen error?

Tags: ios, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

Develop a mobile app with sencha touch hybrid mobile app.

android with Cordova package is working fine

when create ios app,

There is no error, it shows a white screen in the app. No error in the background also. Emulator and device both coming white blank screen

Answer (score 0):

Something tells me you are facing a loading delay issue - i think i have ran into something similar a few years ago and now my common practice is:

Try those steps:

1. Create main.html file on the same level as index.html
2. Copy and paste all your index.html contents to the main.html
3. In you index.html paste this:

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
    <head>
        <title>App Title</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover" />
        <script>
            window.location = './main.html';
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
   ```

It possibly might do the trick